# Map network drives based on IP/subnet and AD group memberships using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using a powershell script like the one below, it looks at AD Security group memberships and based on that it maps drives for the users. What I am trying to accomplish is that when it sees users log on from a certian IP or Subnet it maps a different set of drives in addition to the ones it grabs from AD group memberships, any insight will be appreciated.

```
    # The section below determines what AD groups is the user member of
    $strName = $env:username

    function get-GroupMembership($DNName,$cGroup){

        $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$strName))"

        $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

        $objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
        $objUser = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $DN = $objUser.distinguishedName

        $strGrpFilter = "(&(objectCategory=group)(name=$cGroup))"
        $objGrpSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $objGrpSearcher.Filter = $strGrpFilter

        $objGrpPath = $objGrpSearcher.FindOne()

        If (!($objGrpPath -eq $Null)){

            $objGrp = $objGrpPath.GetDirectoryEntry()

            $grpDN = $objGrp.distinguishedName
            $ADVal = [ADSI]"LDAP://$DN"

            if ($ADVal.memberOf.Value -eq $grpDN){
                $returnVal = 1
                return $returnVal = 1
            }else{
                $returnVal = 0
                return $returnVal = 0

            }

        }else{
                $returnVal = 0
                return $returnVal = 0

        }

    }

    # The section below maps network drives based on users AD Security Group memberships

    $result = get-groupMembership $strName "SecurityGrtoup1"
    if ($result -eq '1') {
        $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("G:");
        $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("G:", "\\server1\Group");
        $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("P:");
        $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("P:", "\\server2\Common");
    }

    $result = get-groupMembership $strName "SecurityGroup3"
    if ($result -eq '1') {
        $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).RemoveNetworkDrive("N:");
        $(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive("N:", "\\Server3\files");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the IPv4 address as a string object:

```
$ip = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress)[0]
```

You could then parse that anyway you need to, you could also instead use the .IPSubnet, or .DefaultIPGateway properties if that would get you what you need.

For other available properties try:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress} | Get-Member
```